# how to check if a filename contains uid in firebase storage security rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want to make  a rules in my firebase storage, and I want the filename of image stored in firebase storage contains uid of its uploader. usually in programming language I use `.contains` to check

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {

    match /eventThumbnail/{imageID} {
      allow create: if request.resource.name.contains(request.auth.uid)
    }
  }
}
```

is this rules valid ? I can't find documentation about using contains in firebase storage security rules documentation. actually the rules is more complex, I still search what makes I fail to create an image, and I suspect that rules is not valid

Comment: How about storing the files of a user in a path segment/folder that is named after thir UID, as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security#user_private)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API documentation for security rules for Cloud Storage is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage).  The specific documentation for string type objects is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#string).  You can see that in the documentation, there is no "contains" method for string.  But there is a method for using a regular expression to verify the contents of a string using [matches()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#matches).

However, I think Frank is correct in his comment suggesting that it would be better to use a dedicated prefix for each user using their UID in the path of the file.  For example "/eventThumbnail/{uid}/{file}" could be used to determine the permissions for any file organized under uid, where uid could simply be verified as equal to `request.auth.uid` (no substrings or regular expression required). This is also far more secure and reliable than checking file substrings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
match /{fileName} {
  allow read: if fileName[0:6] == 'abcdef';
}
```

Documentation on string rules:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#string

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is too late but it it can help others.
We can use the regular expression to achieve it.

```
match /eventThumbnail/{imageID} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && imageID.matches(request.auth.uid + '.*')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Filename can now be used as UID and matched using Firebase storage split syntax found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#split).

I do also recommend rather using the path to prefix each UID instead, but if the files are already in a production environment the split syntax could prove useful.

Update:
Syntax on Firebase Documentation appears to be incorrect as indicated by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64561603/7672893)